# Birt Automatically render report to xlsx when you choose to render to xls

Tags: javascript, java, report, birt, xlsx

i want Birt to automatically render my report to xlsx whenever i choose to render to xls.

Can somebody please help me with this. much thanks.

Comment: "Can somebody please help me with this" is not a proper question in SO, please make a concrete question so you can get an answer.

Comment: To improve this question, list the version of BIRT you are using, which emitter you are using and what you have tried that did not work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i am using Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.4.2. i was not able to try anything yet. I just have a problem implementing the export to .xlsx in a webapplication that we have made, it can only render to .xls. so I thought it might be helpful to just put some code in the Birt .rptdesign that automatically renders the report in .xlsx whenever someone chooses .xls. Have any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the default emitter for XLS and XLSX is the same.

```
emitterID = engine.getConfig( ).getDefaultEmitter( format );
```

(for xls and xlsx is the same emitterID).

You can override it with:

```
engine.getConfig().setDefaultEmitter(format, emitterId);
```

unfortunately, I cannot tell you what to put as `emitterId`.

Edit:

emitterID for XLSX: `uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsxEmitter`

emitterID for XLS: `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.prototype.excel` (problably should be: `uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.XlsEmitter`)

Answer (score 0):

In the file /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/birt/WEB-INF/viewer.properties

```
viewer.extension.html=html
viewer.extension.pdf=pdf
viewer.extension.postscript=ps
viewer.extension.doc=doc
viewer.extension.xls=xls
viewer.extension.ppt=ppt
viewer.extension.ods=ods
viewer.extension.odt=odt
viewer.extension.odp=odp
viewer.extension.docx=docx
viewer.extension.pptx=pptx
viewer.extension.xlsx=xls
viewer.extension.xls_spudsoft=xls
```